# Devise (via API) recoverable : reset_password_token can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I found some discussions and topics about the recoverable feature, but couldn't fix the issue I encounter.

I have a front end API that uses a rails 3.2 backend ( with Devise 2.2.4)
all routes are working well but when I try to update the password it sends a json resonse (in Postman ) :

```
"reset_password_token" : "can't be blank"
```

If I understand the feature :

1- The POST # POST /resource/password sends the reset password to the email ( used as param )
2- then I perform a GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef that goes to my FrontEnd page with a password input.
3- when the password is changed I launch a # PUT /resource/password

This is where the error occures.

Here is the password_controller.rb file :

```
class Devise::PasswordsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication
  # Render the #edit only if coming from a reset password email link
  append_before_filter :assert_reset_token_passed, :only => [:edit, :update]

# GET /resource/password/new
def new
  build_resource({})
end

# POST /resource/password
def create
  self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

  if successfully_sent?(resource)
    #respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    render json: { message: "mail sent"}, status: 200
  else
    #respond_with(resource)
    render json: { :status }
  end
 end

 # GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef
 def edit
  self.resource = resource_class.new
  resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
 end

 # PUT /resource/password
 def update
  self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(params[:reset_password_token])
  if resource.errors.empty?
  resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
  flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
  set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_navigational_format?
  #sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  #respond_with resource, :location => after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
  render json: { message: "password updated"}, status: 200
 else
  respond_with resource
 end
end

protected
 def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
  after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 end

# The path used after sending reset password instructions
def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  new_session_path(resource_name) if is_navigational_format?
end

# Check if a reset_password_token is provided in the request
def assert_reset_token_passed
  if params[:reset_password_token].blank?
    #set_flash_message(:error, :no_token)
    #redirect_to new_session_path(resource_name)
    render json: { message: "reset password is not blank"}, status: 200
  end
end

# Check if proper Lockable module methods are present & unlock strategy
# allows to unlock resource on password reset
def unlockable?(resource)
  resource.respond_to?(:unlock_access!) &&
    resource.respond_to?(:unlock_strategy_enabled?) &&
    resource.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email)
end
end
```

The recoverable.rb method reset_password_by_token :

```
   def reset_password_by_token(attributes={})
      recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:reset_password_token, attributes[:reset_password_token])
      if recoverable.persisted?
        if recoverable.reset_password_period_valid?
          recoverable.reset_password!(attributes[:password], attributes[:password_confirmation])
      else
        recoverable.errors.add(:reset_password_token, :expired)
      end
    end
    recoverable
  end

  Devise::Models.config(self, :reset_password_keys, :reset_password_within)
```

I tried to add some puts on the methods and they are not thrown in the backlog. 
Here is my rails s log :

```
Started PUT "/users/password" for 192.168.0.18 at 2016-04-06 09:35:11 +0200
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
, :options=>{:count=>1, :default=>["User"]}, :description=>"User"}, {:key=>"activerecord.attributes.user.confirmation_token", :locale=>:en, :options=>{:count=>1, :default=>[:"attributes.confirmation_token", "Confirmation token"]}, :description=>"Confirmation token"}, {:key=>"activerecord.attributes.user.unconfirmed_email", :locale=>:en, :options=>{:count=>1, :default=>[:"attributes.unconfirmed_email", "Unconfirmed email"]}, :description=>"Unconfirmed email"}, {:key=>"activerecord.attributes.user.email", :locale=>:en, :options=>{:count=>1, :default=>[:"attributes.email", "Email"]}, :description=>"Email"}, {:key=>"activerecord.attributes.user.reset_password_token", :locale=>:en, :options=>{:count=>1, :default=>[:"attributes.reset_password_token", "Reset password token"]}, :description=>"Reset password token"}]}
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2174ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

===================

*EDIT*

===================

To understand where the request comes from I add below the PUT request on Angular/FrontEnd part :

```
  users.newPassword = function (token, password) {
    var putData = {
     user:{
       reset_password_token: token,
       password: password
     }
  };
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setFullResponse(true);
    }).one('/users/password').customPUT(putData);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the fix. 
The fact is that Devise is waiting params as user Array.
I was sending `reset_password_token` directly, but Devise is waiting `user[reset_password_token]` .....

also the generated token was not the good one. 
In my mail template I had :

`You asked to <%= link_to 'reset your password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @resource.reset_password_token %>.`

And I modified it to

`You asked to <%= link_to 'reset your password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token %>.`

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring **reset_password_by_token** as class method. Thats fine. But you didn't pass either **resource object or reset_password_token** as argument to method. That means don't setting resent_token.

You can debug and check if resource is setting  reset_password_token or not. If yes then follow below

```
self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
```

so, either use

```
resource.reset_password_by_token(params[:password])
```

or

```
resource_class.reset_password_by_token(params[:password], params[:reset_password_token])
```

Comment: Yes, I did a mistake on the first params passed : it's not `confirmation_token`but `reset_password_token`I updated the post. Now I'm trying your proposal.

Comment: I changed the update method with `resource_class.reset_password_by_token(params[:password], params[:reset_password_token])` but still have the 422 error with "can't be blank". In the server logs I have the 2 parameters : `Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}`

Comment: The fact is that I tried to add puts in all the methods of this controller and now one pops on logs. I think there is something else that catches the error before calling the update method. But I don't know how Devise is managed.